# Can I stop mutt from asking for the recipient when pressing m to send a new email?

Tags: email, mutt

When I press `m` to send a new email in Mutt, it first asks for the recipient
("To" header), and then for the Subject. After that, it opens the email in Vim
so I can actually write my email.
I've set `edit_headers` in my `muttrc` file so that I can just add recipients
and such from Vim, so the contents of the new file is:

```
From: Martin Tournoij <martin@arp242.net>
To: example@example.com
Cc:
Bcc:
Subject: Hey there
Reply-To:
```

The issue is, I use a Vim function to complete email addresses, so I don't know
the correct email address before I've started Vim. I work around this by filling
in "asdf" or some such when mutt asks for the recipient.

Is there any way I can tell mutt to skip asking for the recipient? I would
prefer if it would *only* skip the recipient, and that it continues to ask for
the Subject, but skipping both (and going straight to Vim) would also be okay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting `autoedit=yes`, composing will go directly to the message editor without prompting for recipient or subject.

Note that you must also have `edit_headers` set.

As @lcd047 mentions, this feature inhibits all the send hooks before calling the editor.